# What is the scope of this variable `instantiated`

Tags: python, class, singleton

I came across Peter Norvig's implement of singleton class here http://norvig.com/python-iaq.html

```
def singleton(object, instantiated=[]):
    "Raise an exception if an object of this class has been instantiated before."
    assert object.__class__ not in instantiated, \
        "%s is a Singleton class but is already instantiated" % object.__class__
    instantiated.append(object.__class__)

class YourClass:
    "A singleton class to do something ..."
    def __init__(self, args):
       singleton(self)
       ...
```

My problem is, if we create two YourClass instances, in the second time, why `instantiated` is not a empty list? What's the scope of `instantiated`?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values):

> **Important warning:** The default value is evaluated only once. This makes a difference when the default is a mutable object such as a list, dictionary, or instances of most classes. It accumulates the arguments passed to it on subsequent calls.

The value of `instantiated` is bound to function definition and is initialized only once when you define `singleton`.

Because of this, every time you call the function, you'll have only one copy of same list:

```
def test(x, instantiated=[]):
    instantiated.append(x)
    print instantiated

>>> test(3)
[3]
>>> test(5)
[3, 5]
>>> test(6)
[3, 5, 6]
```

It is same as:

```
>>> lst = []

>>> def test(x, instantiated):
...     instantiated.append(x)
...     print instantiated

>>> test(3, lst)
[3]
>>> test(5, lst)
[3, 5]
>>> test(6, lst)
[3, 5, 6]
```

If you want `instantiated` to be isolated between subsequent function calls, you should define it as a `local variable`:

```
def test(x, instantiated=None):
    if instantiated is None:
        instantiated = []
    instantiated.append(x)
    print instantiated

>>> test(3)
[3]
>>> test(5)
[5]
>>> test(6)
[6]
```

Comment: Awesome, Are there any related Python document about it? Thank you.

Comment: I found it. https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values. Thank you again.

Comment: Yeah I was just about to update my answer with that. Good to see you've found it.